# Magento log file permission issues

Tags: magento

I have a standard Magento application where actions are performed either through web (www-data) or cron scripts (executed by a cron user). By default, Magento creates log files with chmod 0640 so this gives us a problem. Whoever logs an exception/system first (www-data or cron), the other won't be able to append. So if an exception occurs on the web, the var/log/exception.log will be created with www-data as owner so cron scripts won't be able to log exceptions in the same file (cron and www-data are not in the same group but even if they would be, it wouldn't help).

Possible solutions:
1. Run cron with same www-data user (sysadmin won't budge, doesn't agree with the solution)
2. Change Mage.php to generate the log files with a more suitable chmod (even 777 maybe). Doable but this means modifying Magento core files (Mage.php) and it's not really allowed by license.

Mage class is final and I noticed there is no pre- or post- events after logging in order to possible change the chmod in a pre/post hook.

Has anybody encountered the same problem or has any advice on how to properly handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed first solution sounds as the valid one to me. The cronjob should run with the `www-data` user. Only then you can guarantee that the file permissions match, regardless if web server or cron job.

Otherwise how can you guarantee that running the cronjob as different user a the web server will give you the same result?

Modifying Mage.php is not a right solution as you already stated. Never modify core files directly as you are going to run into problems when updating Magento - e. g. overwriting files.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the web user should not be same user like the shell/cronjob user. They can use the same group, but different users are more secure.

In our case web/http-user is:

- httpd:site

and shell/cron user is:

- prod:site

So users are different, but belong to the same group. For our case log permission 640 is too restrictive.

Its done in Mage.php

```
chmod($logFile, 0640);
```

We change them by script from 0640 to 0660 by s simple script

```
$command = 'find '.realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/var/log/ -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} +';
exec ($command);
```

which is executed by cron shell and wget